# Generalisations belong to any affine open subset of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I was reading the proof of Lemma 26.13.2. [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J5) and it seems they use the following fact, but I haven't been able to find a proof of it. Could anyone provide a reference/proof?

> Let $X$ be a scheme and $x,x'\in X$ points. Suppose that $x\in\overline{\{x'\}}$, this is, $x'$ is a *generalisation* if $x$. If $U\subseteq X$ is an affine open neighbourhood of $x$, then $x'\in U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a general topological result. If $X$ is a topological space and  $Y \subset X$ then $x 
\in \bar{Y}$ if and only if we have $U \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ whenever $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Oh... I don't know why I didn't realise that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone.